# Eigenvalues of a submatrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

A self-adjoint matrix $A$ in a complex linear space has real eigenvalues bounded between $0$ and $1$.

If $A$ is projected onto an arbitrary two-dimensional subspace, what would be the bounds on the corresponding two eignvalues? I am almost sure they will also be between $0$ and $1$ as well, but need to prove it.

**EDIT:** Here is a more explicit formulation of what is meant by projection:

I take two arbitrary orthonormal column vectors $x$ and $y$ , and make the following $2 \times 2$ matrix:

$$ B =\begin{pmatrix} x^{\dagger} A x & x^{\dagger} A y  \\   y^{\dagger} A  x &  y^{\dagger} A  y   \end{pmatrix}$$

Orthonormal means $x^{\dagger} x =  y^{\dagger} y =1$ and $x^{\dagger} y =0$.

What are the bounds on the eigvevalues of $B$?

Comment: I don't understand the sentence 'If $A$ is projected onto an arbitrary two-dimensional subspace'. How does it relate to $A$'s submatrices?

Comment: @GitGud I'll edit to be more explicit

Comment: use (semi)definiteness (if i understand you correctly)

Comment: my suggestion would be to write $x$ and $y$ as linear combinations and use orthogonality of the original basis. probably you can choose your original basis as on-basis which is diagonalising $A$.

Comment: @max This argument proves quickly that $B_{xx}$ and $B_{yy}$ are between $0$ and $1$ but I'm worried about the off-diagonal element.

Comment: read my last comment, maybe the comment about the semidefiniteness doesn't help (that's why i post comments and no answers, i'm to lazy to check my ideas :P but sometimes they're good.) and yes, your edit did help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a = x^\dagger Ax$, $b = y^\dagger Ay$, and $c = x^\dagger Ay$. The eigenvalues of $B$ are determined by 
$$\lambda_\pm =\frac{a+b\pm\sqrt{(a-b)^2+4\vert c\vert ^2}}{2}.$$ 
Since $0\leq a,b\leq 1$ by assumption, then having $0\leq \lambda_{\pm}\leq1$ is equivalent to 
$$(a+b)^2\geq (a-b)^2+4\vert c\vert^2\qquad (1)$$ 
and
$$ \left(2-a-b\right)^2\geq \left(a-b\right)^2+4\vert c\vert^2.\qquad (2)$$
It is straightforward to show (1) using Cauchy-Schwarz with vectors $A^{1/2}x$ and $A^{1/2}y$. For (2), after simplifying the equivalent expressions we obtain is 
$$(1-a)(1-b)\geq \vert c\vert^2.\qquad(2')$$ 
Note that $1-a = x^\dagger\left(I-A\right)x$, $1-b = y^\dagger\left(I-A\right)y$, and $c = -x^\dagger\left(I-A\right)y$. Therefore, (2') is also provable by a simple application of Cauchy-Schwarz with vectors $\left(I-A\right)^{1/2}x$ and $\left(I-A\right)^{1/2}y$.